# What to do with Electronics questions?

Tags: discussion

Allot of questions are pure Electronics theory questions. People trying to drive motors with GPIO pins or running out or power.

They require to build specialist circuits, that the Pi will drive. In this case it does not matter if they use a Pi, Arduino or PIC.

But they come here looking for help instead of electronics exchange because they are using a Pi to do this.

There is only a "belongs on Linux/Ubuntu". Should we have a "belongs on Electronics Exchange" ?

Comment: Related: http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/24/raspberry-pi-itself-vs-specific-os-issues  It's probably worth considering the same consensus

Answer (score 5):

Yes, most definitely. I've been meaning to do this for a while.

I submitted;

> Questions primarily about **electronics and circuitry** are off-topic when they are not directly related to the Raspberry Pi. Please use [Electronics Stack Exchange](http://electronics.stackexchange.com).

I also reworded the other two to make them sound slightly more official. They just need the approval of another mod.

> Questions focussed on **Linux usage** are off-topic here as they are not directly related to the Raspberry Pi. Please use [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

-

> Questions regarding **orders and related** customer support for the Raspberry Pi are off-topic here. Stack Exchange is not affiliated with the Raspberry Pi Organisation and as such cannot advise on issues of this nature.

Comment: The question is, how do you define "directly related to the RPI"? Is asking about how to setup dns on the RPI off topic? What about how to hook up a generic i2c rtc?